# git ignore tries to commit the changes even after they have been added to .gitignore

Tags: laravel, git

i accidently added some of storage files to my git repository that i want to remove them from local machine now but they have to remain on server . so what i did is cloning the project on my local machine and then added this line to my `.gitignore` :

```
/storage/app/public/product
```

and after that i removed the files from my local machine.
now when i make change on other files it tries to commit the changes which was made on that files and tries to remove them on repository too . now what i want is
1-remove them from local machine and not commit them
2-remove them from repository and it wont remove them on live server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+files+from+repository+leave+on+server

Answer (score 0):

Remove git cache by running below codes

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Then:

```
git add .
```

And at the end commit

```
git commit
```

Comment: Doesn't answer poin 2: the files will be removes from the server.